# Set option just for one command

Tags: vimrc

I was looking for a way to set `virtualedit=block` before executing visual block select with additional binding `g<C-v>` and after that turning it off.

There are few things in my workflow that require that behavior. I didn't find anything after some research. So currently I have this in my vimrc.

```
nnoremap g<C-v> :setl virtualedit=block<CR><C-v>
nnoremap <C-v> :setl virtualedit=<CR><C-v>
```

Another example is to disable `incsearch` for custom command

```
nnoremap <silent> K :setl nois<CR>:grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:setl is<CR>
```

So my question is, is there right or just better than the one I came up with way to set option just for one command and switch it back after command is done?

**Update**
Here is example of function that can help with second case

```
function! Example()
  let &l:virtualedit="block"
  exe "normal \<C-v>"
  let &l:virtualedit=""
endfunction
```

But this way does not work for cases like in first example

Comment: Why do you need virtual edit in visual block? In case if you need to select till end when some lines are longer than or shorter than each other, ten you can press $. Can you tell me y you need virtual edit? I will know more about it from you  :)

Comment: @SibiCoder It is just some times useful to operate exactly on square space even when there is no data to be selected. But question is not really about visualedit, but about setting option. Because for example i have this `nnoremap <silent> K :setl nois<CR>:grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:setl is<CR>` as you see i have to turn off incsearch and turn it on after searching.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Hey, I have heard about `virtualedit` a while ago but I have never really find a use case where I'll need to use it. So, Can you may be tell me more about what you use this feature for and how that is useful with the `block` setting on compared to the default?

Comment: Just `:set ve=block` -- isn't that what it's for?

Comment: @Antony I am talking about setting it temporarily. Just for one command/movement/action

Comment: So sometimes you want to use `<c-v>` with `:set ve=block` and sometimes without? I'm just curious about the use case if that is so.

Comment: I'd just map a key to toggle `'ve'` on and off if you're doing that a lot. Or carry on doing what you're doing: it seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop With `virtualedit=block` it just more visual, you can see exactly rectangle on selected area. Also it is helpful when creating text tables.

Answer (score 3):

You could try calling a function from your mappings, which would save the current value of the relevant option, change the option, set an `autocmd` (with [events](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events) such as `ShellCmdPost`/`QuickFixCmdPost` for grep/vimgrep, and `CursorMoved`/`CursorMoved` for the visual block), and then run the original command.

But note that there may be better alternatives than switching those options. For example, if are creating a mapping for `:grep` and wishes to disable [`'ignorecase'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27ignorecase%27) (because as far as I understand [`'incsearch'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27incsearch%27) won't affect this command) then you could add [`\C`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/%5CC) in the begging of the pattern and leave the option unchanged.

There are also some options which are commonly changed during a workflow. For those, you could try using [unimpaired plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired):

```
OPTION TOGGLING                                 unimpaired-toggling

On      Off     Toggle  Option
[ob     ]ob     cob     'background' (dark is off, light is on)
[oc     ]oc     coc     'cursorline'
[od     ]od     cod     'diff' (actually |:diffthis| / |:diffoff|)
[oh     ]oh     coh     'hlsearch' (coh: first |:nohlsearch|, then |'nohlsearch'|)
[oi     ]oi     coi     'ignorecase'
[ol     ]ol     col     'list'
[on     ]on     con     'number'
[or     ]or     cor     'relativenumber'
[os     ]os     cos     'spell'
[ou     ]ou     cou     'cursorcolumn'
[ov     ]ov     cov     'virtualedit'
[ow     ]ow     cow     'wrap'
[ox     ]ox     cox     'cursorline' 'cursorcolumn' (x as in crosshairs)
```

---

**Edit:**

If you are looking for *native* solutions, them you should look in the built-in documentation. There are some commands for a few options, such as `:noswapfile`:

```
:nos[wapfile]   {command}           *:nos* *:noswapfile*
        Execute {command}. If it contains a command that loads a new
        buffer, it will be loaded without creating a swapfile and the
        'swapfile' option will be reset.  If a buffer already had a
        swapfile it is not removed and 'swapfile' is not reset.
```

There is also `:noautocmd`, which disables autocmds. To search for more, you could try `:help :no<ctrl-d>` to list the possible matches in the documentation that starts with `:no`, or use `:helpgrep`.

In addition to the mapping+function workaround suggested above, you could implement a custom commands for options not covered by the built-in functionality -- this approach is used by some plugins, such as [ProjectRoot](https://github.com/dbakker/vim-projectroot/blob/master/doc/projectroot.txt#L112).

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't really answer the question. But yeah, there plenty similar workarounds, I was looking for native solution that will work for all cases, if it exists.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I've included additional info to the answer.